OpenCV play video without waitKey
I'm trying to play a video with OpenCV in Python. For that I use this code:
i = 0
while True:
    frame = frames[i]
    cv2.imshow("video", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(int(1000 / frame_rate))
    i += 1

But once the user uses his keyboard, the playback speed changes and the video plays in a "fast-forward" mode. I don't need key detection, so I tried to replace the waitKey with time.sleep but the video is not playing at all.
How can I prevent the keyboard from changing the playback speed?

OpenCV is not a GUI library. use a proper GUI library. or a game library. OpenCV is not for making games or any GUI things. nor for making video players. -- GUIs aren't trivial. waitKey() does event processing. this is vital for a GUI. you cannot just substitute a sleep() in place for it. -- you could maintain the timing of frame presentation yourself, by figuring out when to advance, and how much to wait.

cv2.waitKey's return value is either -1 if no key has been pressed during the delay, or an integer corresponding to a keystroke if a key was pressed. You can use this to check whether or not the delay was used, and introduce a delay using time.sleep if a keystroke interrupted the delay:
import time

i = 0
while True:
    frame = frames[i]
    cv2.imshow("video", frame)
    keypress = cv2.waitKey(int(1000 / frame_rate))
    if keypress >= 0:              # a key is being pressed
        time.sleep(1 / frame_rate) # wait for 1 / frame_rate seconds
    i += 1

Edit: note that OpenCV requires waitKey to be used to show an image. An additional workaround would be using matplotlib.imshow (like in this answer) but this is much slower than OpenCV.

For some reason, when key is down (for few seconds, the video freezes)

yeah that's because OpenCV is not a GUI library. this is what happens when you reach the limits of OpenCV's built in convenience graphical display facilities. -- also, extra sleep() in any GUI event loop, as this answer suggests, is asking for trouble. -- this answer also doesn't actually keep the video playing nicely under keypresses. any waitKey() that is ended prematurely with a keypress will cause an entire's frame delay on top of what was already spent by that waitKey() call.
